# sticky header with scrollView and stackview

Tags: ios, header, scrollview, sticky

I know that the sticky header is not a new thing to ask advice on, but still...

I am trying to create a sticky header (UIImageView) and the scrolling part (UIScrollView with a UIStackView in it)

Im using the `scrollViewDidScroll` method from the `UIScrolLViewDelegate`. The only problem is, that when I scroll the view up, I am not only decreasing the height of the header view, but also scrolling the content of the stack view. So when I scroll further up, you still can see the header view, but the top content of the scroll view disappears by scrolling.

Can this be solved somehow that when I scroll up, the content of the stack view is scrolling up and not also disappearing? And starts disappearing when the header view disappears?

Thank you

Comment: you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use a table view. Your sticky header is the table's first section header, while the scrolling part is the second section.

If you can't use a table, for whatever reason, then you have to mess around with the scroll view's content offset. When the `contentOffset.y` is growing (but not beyond your header's height), reset it to 0 and decrease the header's height accordingly. After the header's height is 0, stop messing with `contentOffset` - until you come back and the `contentOffset.y` wants to go into negatives.

P.S. the second solution requires you to enable bouncing on the scroll view. Otherwise, the header will be hidden, but won't show again (unless you reset the controller)

L.E. Some (old) code for my second solution:

```
let headerHeight = self.headerView.height
self.scrollHandler = {
    var offset = self.detailsTable.contentOffset

    self.headerTopConstraint.constant -= offset.y
    if self.headerTopConstraint.constant < -headerHeight {
        self.headerTopConstraint.constant = -headerHeight

        let size = self.detailsTable.contentSize
        if offset.y + self.detailsTable.frame.height > size.height {
            offset.y = size.height - self.detailsTable.frame.height
        }

        self.detailsTable.contentOffset = offset
    }
    else {
        if self.headerTopConstraint.constant > 0 {
            self.headerTopConstraint.constant = 0
        }
        self.detailsTable.contentOffset = CGPointZero
    }
}
```

Please note that my code moved the header upwards to hide it. As far as I understood, you just have to change the header's height (by the same amount I move it upwards).

Comment: But when I set the scrollView.contentOffset.y within the `scrollViewDidScroll`, it's called again and it resets the offset to 0 and I can't scroll again right?

Comment: @kalafun I added a piece of code I used in a similar case.

Comment: Obviously, your scrollview is a table in my case (detailsTable).